# CMS framework suitable for educational website

Tags: content-management-system

I am building a educational site for carpentry.
It will contain lost of articles and tutorials sorted in different categories.
I am looking for suitable CMS and/or theme. 
The focus is on content and ease of organizing lots of links ion categories. So I don't care about beautiful visual design, but rather a neat way to organize a lot of information on a topic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm what's the world's leading example of a lot of information on just about every topic? Wikipedia. And the software that runs Wikipedia, 'mediawiki', is free and open-source. You could try that.

It might take a bit of getting used to, since there's no hierarchy of URLs (so for example you dont have /tutorials/cabinets/tutorial1.html) but everything can be in multiple categories by tagging: [[category:tutorial]] [[category:cabinetmaking]] etc. And the power comes in search and rich linking.

I put this out as an alternative to the standard Drupal/Joomla/LAMP-stack CMSs that other people will doubtless suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Educational site? Maybe you're looking for an LMS instead?

Check edu 2.0 at http://www.edu20.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the specific features of an LMS - grading, testing, etc then Joomla or Drupal would easily be able to do what you are looking for. Both are very good at organizing content.